# Elastic search filter creation

Tags: sql, elasticsearch

Hi I am struggling with Elastic search filter creation. so there is a existing query which look likes this:

```
 {
   "query":{
      "bool":{
         "must":[
            {
               "match":{
                  "account_id":1231231231
               }
            },
            {
               "multi_match":{
                  "fuzziness":"AUTO",
                  "query":"topics",
                  "type":"most_fields",
                  "fields":[
                     "title.value^11",              
                     "parent_name^4",
                     "*"
                  ],
                  "operator":"and"
               }
            }
         ],
         "filter":[
            
         ],
         "must_not":{
            "terms":{
               "published_status.raw":[
                  "Disabled"
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "_source":[
      "node_type",
      "parent_name",
      "node_name",
      "title",
    
   ],
   "size":5,
   "indices_boost":{
      "tables":7,
      "columns":1
   },
   "sort":[
      "_score",
      {
         "tbl_popularity_info.NoOfTimeUsed":{
            "order":"desc",
            "unmapped_type":"long"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

So Now Thing is I have to add two conditioning in it . in which 1 is to have include records containing ID's of specific type and 2nd is excluding on basis of ID's . Currently I have SQL of that condition (using in Relational db to query same data) . which is :

`where (( dmn_id in (123,301)) or ( cat_id in (300))) and not (( coalesce(trm_status_id,'' ) in ('SUG') ) AND ( string_to_array(coalesce(tag_ids,'' ),',') && ARRAY['314'] ) )`

So according to my understanding I am creating this way:

```
"filter": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "terms": {
                  "dmn_id": [123,301]
                }
              },
              {
                "terms": {
                  "cat_id": [300]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
      "bool": {
        "must_not": [
          {
            "bool": {
              "must": [
                {
                  "terms": {
                    "trm_status": ["SUG"]
                  }
                },
                {
                  "terms": {
                    "tags": ["314"]
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
         
        }
      ]
```

**So eventually  my final query is now :**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "account_id": 1231231231
          }
        },
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "fuzziness": "AUTO",
            "query": "topics",
            "type": "most_fields",
            "fields": [
              "title.value^11",
              "parent_name^4",
              "*"
            ],
            "operator": "and"
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "terms": {
                  "dmn_id": [123,301]
                }
              },
              {
                "terms": {
                  "cat_id": [300]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must_not": [
              {
                "bool": {
                  "must": [
                    {
                      "terms": {
                        "trm_status": ["SUG"]
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "terms": {
                       "tags": ["314"]
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": {
        "terms": {
          "published_status.raw": ["Disabled"]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "_source": [
    "node_type",
    "node_sub_type",
  ],
  "size": 5,
  "indices_boost": {
    "tables": 7,
    "datasets": 5,
    "terms": 3,
    "columns": 1
  },
  "sort": [
    "_score",
    {
      "tbl_popularity_info.NoOfTimeUsed": {
        "order": "desc",
        "unmapped_type": "long"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

So this is my query logically right ? Or I am doing this wrong way ?

Answer (score 1):

That's correct, your filter conditions seem fine. You can just simplify a bit the second part (must_not) to this since `must_not` already has AND semantics.

```
    {
      "bool": {
        "must_not": [
           {
             "terms": {
               "trm_status": ["SUG"]
             }
           },
           {
             "terms": {
              "tags": ["314"]
             }
           }
        ]
      }
    }
```

Comment: thanks for reply , can you please verify if  must_not  in my query and your suggested change doing same thing ?

Comment: Yes, it's the same, everything in must_not MUST NOT match, so it's like what you did with must_not+must, just simpler

Comment: thanks for clearing , last question  am I putting this in right place ? like in filter

Comment: Yes, all the rest is correct, everything that you want to match exactly goes into the bool/filter section as that isn't involved in ranking/scoring like everything that you put in bool/must. What do you get when you execute the query? That's the ultimate test